# Connecting to SharePoint intranet site with designer error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

Error message is:

```
The Web server at "http://bruce" does not appear to have Microsoft SharePoint Foundation installed.
```

Versions of SharePoint and SP Designer are 2013, and it's running SharePoint Server 2013.

It actually has, and I've also tried [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981223) and this was already done as well, and enabling SharePoint Designer on SharePoint settings on the site.

So I'm pretty stuck with this. Any advice/help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this ? I'm also getting the same error.

Comment: Yes reinstalling SharePoint did the trick sadly :(

Comment: Oh. I need to reinstall again! :(

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling web integration (central admin, web app, Default and select 'enable client integration')

Also add the site to your trusted sites, using IE sign-in to the SharePoint site and then open SPD by using Site Settings -> Edit in SharePoint Designer.

Sometimes when my laptop is not member of the network I'm on. I also have to add the url to my Windows 'hosts file'. But this is more a networking / proxy issue rather than SharePoint.